# Kannel : Is it safe to ignore delivery report status 8 (Delivered to SMSC)

Tags: kannel

When we develop our system we have ignored DR status `8 (Delivered to SMSC)` on Kannel as it always call back to us when sending SMS. So we have heavy traffic load to our system and we have ignored that status. We are currently supporting following status.

```
1: Delivered to phone,
2: Non-Delivered to Phone,
4: Queued on SMSC,
16: Non-Delivered to SMSC
```

If we didn't get any any of above status from Kannel DR is it safe to assume that we have successfully send message to SMSC?

Our Kannel version is 1.4.1.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is important to have SMSC delivery because when you have a problem with SMS delivery. The first step is to check whether error is on your side or the recipient SMSC.
That could be the difference between 5 minutes and 30 minutes of debugging. Cheers!